# Install node js on centos

Tags: node.js, installation, centos

To install node js. I am referring this url  `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server`

but when I try extract source with this command `tar xzvf node-v* && cd node-v*`

I get error `tar: node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin/npm: Cannot create symlink to`../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js': Protocol error`

Answer (score 1):

**INSTALLING NODE.JS FROM EPEL REPOSITORY**

An alternative method of installing node.js is from the Epel Repository that is available for CentOS and other linux distro's. To get access to the repo you must first install the epel-release by.

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Press `y` for yes and let it install.

After that you can just install node.js from yum.

```
sudo yum install nodejs
```

To verify the installed version you can do.

```
node --version
```

Refer : https://www.vpsserver.com/community/tutorials/20/install-node-js-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzvf node-v* -C /usr/local
```